# Nvidia Xavier NX not detect FTDI USB adapter

Tags: serial-port, usb, uart, ftdi, jetson-xavier

I try to interface UM7 imu sensor with Nvidia jetson xavier NX. I used [this FTDI USB adapter](https://www.generationrobots.com/en/403282-usb-expansion-board-for-um7-orientation-sensor.html). But xavier nx not detect the USB port. I installed the FTDI D2XX driver to xavier NX from [this site](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d2xx-drivers/). Still not work.
I connect UM7 to my jetson nano and my laptop, it’s work fine.

Jetson Xavier NX:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- JETPACK VERSION 4.6.2
- L4T VERSION 32.2.1

When i run `$ lsusb` in my Jetson nano

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When i run `$ lsusb` in Xavier NX

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1bcf:08b8 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0461:4e04 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This device not found in xavier

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

Comment: The Jetson Xavier NX is a module and doesn't have USB. Are you referring to the development kit? If so, have you plugged it into one of the 4 USB-A connectors (and not into the Micro USB)? And even without the FTDI drivers, the device should be listed with lsusb.

Comment: Yes, It is Nvidia Jetson Xavier NX dev kit